# How to create a simple Kafka mock service for wiremocks?

Tags: apache-kafka, mocking, wiremock

We have a service which isn't in the scope of our performance test and we're trying to build a light weight service to replace it in Java so that it can:

- Consume Kafka messages to a serviceA
- Send requests to a serviceA

We're building the service from scratch to use with some wiremocks, and at the moment it's hard to visualise what it would look like it

Relatively new to kafka and I have searched online and asked around but not many people know how to make a simple mock kafka service that can be used with our wiremocks - wondering if anyone had any experience of doing something similar especially when using wiremocks?

Any kind of information or starting points/ resources etc would all be super helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Wiremock is for HTTP, last I checked, not TCP services like Kafka... Kafka already has its own `MockProducer` and `MockConsumer` classes

Comment: Also, since I removed spring-kafka tag, you should check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#testing

Comment: It's generally easier to use an embedded broker, or TestContainers for testing (or the mocks provided by the `kafka-clients` as @OneCricketeer mentioned). We recently added `MockConsumerFactory` and `MockProducerFactory` to Spring for Apache Kafka (3.0.x) to make it a bit easier to use those mocks. They will be in 3.0.7 which will be released next week. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2673